# wai-app-static 2.0.1 installation with cabal-install fails

Tags: haskell, dependencies, yesod, cabal-install

I'm trying to install git-annex with cabal-install. It has yesod (and wai-app-static) as a dependency, but the latter fails to build with the following message:

```
/home/prvak master # cabal install git-annex -v
Reading available packages...
Choosing modular solver.
Resolving dependencies...
Ready to install wai-app-static-2.0.1
...
Building wai-app-static-2.0.1...
creating /tmp/wai-app-static-2.0.1-5064/wai-app-static-2.0.1/dist/setup
/root/.cabal/setup-exe-cache/setup-Cabal-1.18.1.3-x86_64-linux-ghc-7.6.3 build
--verbose=2
Redirecting build log to {handle: /root/.cabal/logs/wai-app-static-2.0.1.log}
Failed to install wai-app-static-2.0.1
Last 10 lines of the build log ( /root/.cabal/logs/wai-app-static-2.0.1.log ):
Loading package unordered-containers-0.2.3.3 ... linking ... done.
Loading package semigroups-0.12.2 ... linking ... done.
Loading package void-0.6.1 ... linking ... done.
Loading package conduit-1.1.0 ... linking ... done.
Loading package blaze-builder-conduit-1.1.0 ... linking ... done.
Loading package case-insensitive-1.2.0.0 ... linking ... done.
Loading package scientific-0.2.0.2 ... linking ... done.
Loading package attoparsec-0.11.2.1 ... linking ... done.
Loading package parsec-3.1.5 ... linking ... ghc: /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-ghc-7.6.3/parsec-3.1.5/HSparsec-3.1.5.o: unknown symbol `textzm1zi1zi0zi1_DataziTextziUnsafe_Iter_con_info'
ghc: unable to load package `parsec-3.1.5'
...
yesod-static-1.2.2.4 depends on wai-app-static-2.0.1 which failed to install.
/home/prvak master #
```

I have more logs in http://pastebin.com/KYkMSwuh, but I got nothing more specific than the 'missing symbol' message.

What can I do about this? I tried to reinstall Parsec, but that didn't help.

**EDIT**: I removed all Haskell packages I installed as packages of my Linux distro (Arch). That didn't help. The `/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-ghc-7.6.3/parsec-3.1.5/` directory is generated by `cabal-install` when it installs Parsec.

I have played around with flags that should rip all the web stuff out of `git-annex`, but that unfortunately didn't help. The culprit seems to be `shakespeare` - it seems to me that even if I disable the installation of its built-in web server `servius` with `-f -servius`, it will still affect the dependencies (e.g. include `wai-app-static`) :(

I tried building Shakespeare myself with the dependencies removed, but that also didn't help. I can't get it to build :( (my attempt with latest Git version: http://pastebin.com/1cJawzYh, and with 2.0.0.1: http://pastebin.com/S1trcRJK)

Comment: How did you install Haskell to start with? It looks like parsec is part of a distro and from the symbol name I'd guess it may be looking for a different version of the text library than the one you are linking against.

Comment: I installed Haskell as an Arch Linux package, but from my package listing, it doesn't look like I have a Parsec Arch Linux package installed. I have, however, installed XMonad as an Arch package, so that might have broken some things. I will uninstall all Haskell packages I have installed as Arch packages and reinstall them with cabal-install and I'll see what will that do...

Comment: Nope, this didn't help. I'll update my question to reflect this.

Comment: Haskell package installation is quite temperamental. I would avoid mixing system packages and cabal installed ones. These days I install GHC myself and maintain draconian checks on my installed package versions. If I want to update a package I unregister everything that depends on it (recursively using `ghc-pkg unregister`) before re-installing. I never have two versions of the same package at the same time. Cabal sandboxes are also an option to avoid conflicts. When I was learning this stuff I found [this site](http://www.vex.net/~trebla/haskell/sicp.xhtml) useful (a bit outdated now).